# CSV import problem since converting to PHP 8.1

Tags: php, csv, fopen, php-8.1

I have the following Wordpress function that worked in PHP 7. Since converting to 8.1, it's not working.

```
function dropdown_handler() {

$output = drop_function();
//send back text to replace shortcode in post
return $output;
}

function drop_function() {
//get the csv file with amounts
if ($file_handle = fopen("wp-content/plugins/drop/amounts.csv", "r")) {
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $lines[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    
}
fclose($file_handle);
$lines = str_replace ("£","&pound;",$lines);

}
else {
echo "Sorry, something went wrong";
}
```

In my error log I'm seeing "PHP Warning: Array to string conversion in" relating to the $lines = str_replace line but I think there's something wrong with the fopen statement.

Basically, the word Array is being stored in the `$lines` variable rather than the contents of the CSV file.
Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was always broken, it's just broken in a slightly more obvious way than it used to be...

```
$lines[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
```

`fgetcsv`, unless it fails, returns an array; you then add this array as a new item to another array, `$lines`. The result is *an array of arrays*, like this:

```
$lines = [
    ['line 1 first item', 'line 1 second item'],
    ['line 2 first item', 'line 2 second item'],
];
```

Later, you pass this whole array to `str_replace`; but `str_replace` only knows how to deal with a *single dimension* of array.

So this works:

```
$singleLine = ['line 1 first item', 'line 1 second item'];
var_dump(str_replace('item', 'ITEM', $singleLine));
```

But this doesn't:

```
var_dump(str_replace('item', 'ITEM', $lines));
```

Running that example [on multiple versions of PHP](https://3v4l.org/F6DNs) reveals that under PHP 7.x, `str_replace` reacted by simply leaving the inner arrays untouched - in other words, it did nothing.

In PHP 8, it instead tries to turn each inner array into a string, issuing the warning and producing the word "Array" (which will then have any substitutions applied to it).

The fix **for both PHP versions** is to run the `str_replace` on each of the inner arrays, most simply by using `array_map`:

```
var_dump(
    array_map(
        fn($innerArray) => str_replace('item', 'ITEM', $innerArray),
        $lines
    )
);
```

Alternatively, you can just delete the `str_replace` line completely, since you were apparently happy enough when it wasn't actually doing anything.